# Подлежащее в предложении

Tags: части-речи

в словосочетании "жизненный опыт" вся конструкция является подлежащим или "жизненный" - определение, а "опыт" - подлежащее?

Comment: А предложение-то Вы и не привели... А потому сказать, каким членом задуманного Вами предложения является слово «опыт» — нельзя. Может быть подлежащим, а может и дополнением. К примеру, в предложении «За время работы в ГДР Путин не только приобрел богатый жизненный опыт, но и довел знание немецкого языка до совершенства» подлежащим будет слово «Путин», «опыт» — дополнением, а «жизненный» — определением...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например: ***При решении  сложных вопросов  требуется жизненный опыт.***

*Опыт* — подлежащее, *жизненный* — определение. Слово ***опыт*** определяется как совокупность знаний, опыт может быть **личным, жизненным, собственным,** то есть к нему могут относиться разные определения.

**ОПЫТ,**  м. 1. **Совокупность знаний, навыков, умения, вынесенных из жизни, практической деятельности** и т.п. Приобретать, передавать о. Делиться опытом. Рассчитывать, полагаться на чей-л. о. Учиться на опыте старших. Убедиться в чём-л. на собственном опыте.  // **Знание жизни**, основанное на пережитом, испытанном. Громадный личный о. Житейский о. О. жизни.